# Best software to convert video to a different aspect ratio for various screensizes

Tags: encoding, video-editing, aspect-ratio

I sometimes get .mp4 and other video formats whose aspect ratio is clearly off
What apps do you use to reconvert such videos to an aspect ratio better suited to to fit either a regular desktop or LCD screen size?
Hopefully with little or no loss of audio/video quality

---

Any instructions on best settings to use would be very welcome. I have so far mostly used vlc which came off with less-than-ideal results.
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I have deleted all comments regarding the duplicates since the content of the question changed.

Comment: The linebreak indicates the new content to the question. I would be most grateful for any related links that you think could still be of help to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) comes to mind. I use that one to turn video's 90 degrees.

I think also [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) can be used for this.

**Edit**: As for your question concerning file size or quality loss. This totally depends on what codec you re-encode to and with which parameters. You can use [gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to see most of the parameters of the original file, and if you specify everything the same (except for the aspect ratio of course) the file size shouldn't be much different and there shouldn't be no quality loss.
If the source file is e.g. an mpeg-1 file, then you can re-encode it to mpeg-4 and make the file much smaller while maintaining the same quality (all depends on parameters of the re-encoder of course).

Comment: Any clue as to whether any loss in quality or increase in filesize?

Answer (score 3):

Another option may be [FormatFactory](http://www.formatoz.com/). I use it for all media conversions.

Answer (score 2):

I used [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) for converting videos for my PSP which involved changing the aspect ratio and it worked really well.

> MediaCoder is a free universal media transcoder since 2005. It integrates most popular audio/video codecs and tools in an elegant and transparent manner into an all-in-one transcoding solution. With a flexible and extendable architecture, latest codecs and tools are updated added in constantly. MediaCoder intends to be the swiss army knife for media transcoding in all time.

Comment: Any idea about any loss in quality or filesize larger than original issues?

Comment: The quality seemed fine to me and the filesize was smaller.  You've got quite a lot of control over bitrate so it should be easy enough to tune it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Some software players have the ability to do such scaling in the player itself.  Of course, this also means that you have to fix it every time you play the video, and other people you give the file to don't see the video correctly.

To fix it correctly, the best way would be to modify the Display Aspect Ratio of the video itself if possible.  Some containers/codecs should allow for this without having to re-encode.  [This discussion](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/change-aspect-ratio-of-mp4-without-re-encoding-t364240.html) goes over modifying MP4 videos.  You might be able to use [mkvtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) to do the same thing with Matroska (.mkv) files.